# Speaker diarization support in Microsoft.CognitiveServices.Speech?

Tags: speech-to-text, azure-cognitive-services

There seems to be some (limited) support for speaker diarization in Microsoft's batch pipeline, but I cannot find any reference to the same in the SDK (we're using Microsoft.CognitiveServices.Speech 1.13.0). Is there some way of requesting speaker diarization using the C# SDK that I'm not aware of? Alternatively, does anyone know if such support is planned in a future version?

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for reaching out. Currently, [Azure Speech Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/speech-service/overview) Batch Speech-to-Text doesn't have SDK support (at the moment there's no public information on when support will be available). However, Azure Speech Service SDK's [ConversationTranscriber API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/speech-service/how-to-use-conversation-transcription) enables real-time speech recognition, speaker identification, and diarization (it's perfect for transcribing in-person meetings with the ability to distinguish speakers). The ConversationTranscriber API is supported for C# as well.